# How to write files to your desktop with the use of an android application using an emulator or USB-connected device using for example Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, file, android-studio

I wrote some classes for my Android-program and it runs. However it takes too much ram because the data in the File is not in a nice form to be processed by the application. Let's call the File `Foo.txt` for now.

I now want to save the data from `Foo.txt` in a different form which lets my Android specific code (specific in the sense that it uses Activities, Context etc) do easily since I have all the code for it already, and then load from this data `manipulatedFooFile.txt` instead. **Problem is, I don't know if it's possible at all to save to a file which I can then later retrieve on the desktop**, either in an emulator or via a device connected to an USB or a way I don't know of yet. This way I can replace `Foo.txt` with `manipulatedFooFile.txt` which would let me use less ram and space on disk.

I know that one other solution would be to remove the code from android and put it into a normal java program. Put that would take a bit of struggle since I have to remove all the dependencies on code that is not there, or start with nothing and write big parts of the code again.

Comment: Can you not use `adb pull` to get the data out?

Comment: i don't get it. it "takes too much ram" or space?

Comment: @CPUTerminator Never heard of that, I will check it out.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Yes it was indeed a little bit vague. But if it's saved in compressed form factor it would take less physical space on disk as well as would require less ram since the data is smaller. Since the data is smaller I could use a different data type to store the data into ram. Taking less space in the process.

Comment: If the data is loaded, uncompressed, to be processed by some part of your program you will be using more RAM than reading from plain-old uncompressed data to start with. This is because you would need space to allocate the compressor/decompressor. In essence, if the entirety of the uncompressed data is required to be loaded at once, compression at file storage is not going to reduce your RAM usage. The only way I see that you can benefit is if you can load and process the compressed file **directly**, which I find unlikely.

Comment: @CPUTerminator I changed my question a little bit.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to store 250k words on an android device and then see if a specific word exists in this very long list of words. I thought that putting an array of longs into memory would be a decent amount less ram than it would take String arrays etc. So I thought about changing the strings into longs, this will result in more storage used on the device but less ram. That's why what I said earlier was wrong, it was not a compressed way of storing this, however it does take significantly less ram.

Comment: Off-topic but, I'd just do partial reads (i.e. read line-by-line using the same string to check if the given string matches). This way, you only ever need space for the length of one line in the file and you can abort reading halfway should a match be found. I can understand if its not possible for you. Anyway, access to files can be done with the program `adb` given as part of the android sdk. Using `adb pull` allows you to retrieve a file from the device whilst `adb push` allows you to put a file onto the device.

Comment: @CPUTerminator I will time this, look how fast that actually is. Thank for the tip.

Comment: @CPUTerminator if you make this an answer I will upvote it and probably accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files and folders can be sent to and from your android device using `adb` (or android debug bridge).

Using the `adb pull` command under the syntax `adb pull <remote> <local>` you are able to transfer a file from the filesystem of the connected android device to your local device (your computer).

From the official documentation for `adb pull`:

> Copies a specified file from an emulator/device instance to your development computer.

Similarly, `adb push` allows you to push a file from your local computer to the target emulator/android device under the syntax `adb push <local> <remote>`.